# How to update multiple tables in single query in OrientDb

Tags: orientdb, orientdb2.2, nosql

How to update multiple tables in single query in OrientDb

I have to update two tables at one short

Comment: HI, can be useful a Js function? Let me now. Thx

Comment: No Cannot use Js function for doing this considering the project scenario